# Eclipse adds @NotNull annotation when content assisting variable initialization

Tags: eclipse

I use Hibernate and therefore the javax.validation.constraints.NotNull annotation on my entity properties. 
Here's my usecase: First I write the following code:

```
myEntity.getName()
```

Then I use Eclipse content assist 'ctrl+1' to get the dropdown choice 'Assign statement to new local variable'.

Now, if the getName() property is annotated with javax @NotNull, the resulting variable is also annoted with @NotNull, like this:

```
@NotNull
String name = myEntity.getName();
```

I don't want this annotation on my variables. How do I turn it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a variant of `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` that contains `TYPE_USE` in its list of `@Target`s, then the annotation is considered to be part of the type.

Eclipse initially proposes to declare the new local variable with the exact same type as the right hand side.

By pressing `TAB` you can navigate to the position of the variable's type and select from a list of suitable types. Selecting any of these types (incl. the original String) by pressing `Enter` causes the annotation to be dropped.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using a really old eclipse version, this was already fixed in eclipse 4.7 (= Eclipse Oxygen), see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=443146.

Current is 4.10 (= Eclipse 2018‑12), downloadable from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Comment: I use Eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)

Comment: In the bug you linked they discuss a different annotation. So either this was fixed only for that specific annotation but not for annotations in general or there is a setting to turn it off or something..?

Comment: Sorry,  I had assumed that you have annotation based null analysis enabled and your @NotNull is configured as one of the annotations. If you do that, the eclipse will understand it and know it is not needed for local variables. Unknown type annotations are currently always kept even for local variables. If you think that should be changed, please file a bug at https://bugs.eclipse.org

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, disabling annotation-based null analysis would be one way to prevent annotations on content assist? Unfortunately annotation-based null analysis is already turned off. So it seems that the behaviour I'm experiencing is intended. Ok, I will file a bug then because I think I have some good reasons why these annotations can be misleading.

Comment: No _enabling_ it should prevent it

Comment: Ah! Ok, so I guess I have to configure 'Use default annotatins for null specifications' and add the javax.NotNull annotation..? So, I added javax.validation.constraints.NotNull to 'NonNull' annotations but content assist still adds the annotation when 'assigning statement to a new variable'. I'm not sure how this null analysis feature relates to the auto-complete feature...

Comment: Thanks. If you enable annotations based analysis, make sure that the configured primary annotations are available on the class path (maybe just configure the annotations on the classpath as primary annotations)